# Time series regression with two dependent variables

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, vector-autoregression, manova

I would like to find a suitable model for the relationship between multiple independent variables and two dependent variables simultaneously. Which model would you recommend me to use? If I understand correctly, VAR is not an option, as I am not interested in finding the lag relationship between dependent variables. Also, if I use multivariate multiple regression (like MANOVA), it does not apply to time series. Then which model should I use?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: In a structural VAR with exogenous variables ("SVARX") you can account for (some) contemporaneous effects, see e.g. https://www.emis.de/journals/RCE/V35/v35n3a09.pdf

Comment: Aww ok! I will take a look, thank you very much @ChristophHanck!